Rotate a triangle from top left or right sides in css
I want to rotate a triangle created with CSS from the top-left or top-right sides. i try some changing origin position but not work fine , i've done a lot of search but don't find anything clear or relative .Is there a way to implement these rotations using CSS?
sample images:


The first triangle is rotated inward from the top-left.
The second triangle is rotated inward from the top-right.
I tried using transform: rotate(), and it's work fine for up to down or backward , but I’m not sure how to change the rotation point to the top-left or top-right.
try to show this rotate with transition .
how can i do somthinge like that ?

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

transform-origin?

it depends on how you create the triangles so share your code

@Paulie_D i try this .. but not work fine ..

Then you need to demonstrate it not working in a Snippet as requested. Note that for you image to work you need an equilateral triangle.

Please make it clear what axis you want the rotation to be about - is this to be 3d or to stay in the plain?

@AHaworth yes , it should be 3D .. in image one , imagine fixed top-right side of triangle .. then flip  triangle .

As others have requested, you need to show us the code that creates the triangle and also what attempts you have made at the rotation.

Let's make an example with a simple square.
Idea is to rotate along the main axis (say Y?), then in order to make it angled like a triangle edge would be, I will rotate the entire thing on another axis (Z).


.square {
  background: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  transition: 1s;
  border-right: 2px solid yellow;
  transform-origin: right;
}

.square-container {
  display: inline-block;
}

.square-container:hover .square {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.square-container {
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
}
<h2>Hover to trigger rotation:</h2>
<div class="square-container">
  <div class="square">
  </div>
</div>



